# Installing multisite network on a bluehost addon domain

Tags: multisite

I have successfully installed multisite on my bluehost primary domain.  When i tried to follow the same steps to set up multisite on another bluehost add-on domain it didn't work.  Is it possible to set up multisite on bluehost add-on domains, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; I have done this without issues. I just installed a basic WP on the add-on domain, then converted it to multisite using the usual instructions.

If already installed, check the two site URL entries in the wp-options table; they should match the root of your site.

Comment: Many thanks for fast answer and  confirmation it can be done.  However, it still doesn't work for me.  I checked wp-options tables in each domain's database and URLs match the root of the relevant site.  Are there any other tweaks you can think of between setting up multisite on primary domain and add-on domain?  And perhaps you use a different provider to Bluehost?

Comment: I have a multisite in an add-on domain on JustHost that works just fine. Been there for about 2+ years. No problems; even have a few sub-sites with their own domain (via the "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" plugin). No special setup required, just followed the 'enable multisite' instructions like this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/ ) . Just worked for me. I use a subdir-type multisite, subdomains are a bit different (see above link). The initial site was an add-on. No tweaks required, just getting used to slight admin diffs.

Comment: Many thanks once again for fast, clear answer and good tip.  Will try using JustHost instead.

Comment: BlueHost and JustHost are owned by the same parent company, and are very similar. I have WP sites on both. So not sure that BlueHost is the problem - or that JustHost will fix it. My comment is that a standard WP install, then modify for multisite, worked fine for me. If possible, start over? Put a new WP install (I usually use their WP install wizard, then remove all of the extra plugins they install), then modify for multisite. If it all works, then point the add-on domain to the new folder.

Comment: Many thanks once again for very helpful reply.  Will do as you suggest and let you know the results.  Will need  a few days.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi  Rick,  I finally got the multisite to work thanks to closely reading your wpbeginner link. I had simply missed the point that you had to disable all plug-ins for the multisite to install !  Now it works fine.